# How to build QueryOver with simple bool condition?

Tags: queryover

one very simple question I believe, I just dont get it:

This method throws an exception:

```
public void SetState( bool active )
{
    Query.Where( q => q.Inactive == !active );
}
```

***Cannot interpret member from Not(value(Business.Filter.EmployeeFilter+<>c__DisplayClass12).active)***

I simply want to attach a bool condition to my query: "WHERE Inactive = true/false"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show how you're calling this method? I'm assuming it's part of a class where `Query` is a field.

Answer (score 0):

this works, but still strange:

```
public void SetState( bool inactive )
{
    Query.Where( q => q.Inactive == inactive );
}
```